# Using console while tkinter window is open

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

Hi i try to use console while a transparent window is running.
So there should be a console and a tkinter window.
Both should be useable.
I tried with multithreading and multiprocessing and both didnt work.
I also tried to make the tkinter window in an extra file and run it with os.system(winow.py) but fo people who dont have python installted that wont work.

```
from threading import Thread
import tkinter
import os
import keyboard
import time

FONT = "{Verdana} 10 bold"

btest = True

txt = """
    Text here
"""
root = tkinter.Tk()

def overlay():
    text = tkinter.Text(root,relief=tkinter.FLAT, 
                font=FONT,state='normal', height=5, bg='grey70', fg='blue')
    text.insert(tkinter.END, txt)
    text.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)     #make it readonly with calling state=diabled    ,state=normal is write
    text.pack(expand=tkinter.YES, fill=tkinter.BOTH)

    button = tkinter.Button(root, text='Exit', bd=1, command=quit)
    button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=tkinter.X)

    text.insert(tkinter.END, txt)

    root.geometry('200x250+1710-820')
    root.overrideredirect(1) # fenster ohne aussen rum :-)

    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.75) # fenster transparent
    root.attributes('-topmost', 1) # fenster immer im vordergrund
    root.mainloop()

def printgui():
    os.system("cls")
    print(f"Test: {btest} [alt]")

Thread(target=printgui()).start()
Thread(target=overlay()).start()

while True:
    if(keyboard.is_pressed("alt")):         #if u press "alt" it will change true to False
        btest = not btest
        time.sleep(0.2)
        printgui()

    if(keyboard.is_pressed("delete")):
        print("\n")
        print("Exiting")
        time.sleep(3)
        os._exit(1)
```

Comment: Change `printgui()` to `printgui`, same thing with `overlay` in your thread starting script

Comment: already tried and didnt work i only get the overlay or the console gui

Comment: After you change that do you get any errors?

Comment: no no error it only shows me the console or the tkinter but not both at the same time

Comment: On this line: `root.geometry('200x250+1710-820')`, why do you have `1710-820`? Both numbers should be +ve and less than your screen size.

Comment: Also you can't create `tk.Tk` in 1 thread and create widgets (that are attached to that window) in a different thread. Try sticking with 1 thread. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: its -820 to reach right upper corner

if it woud be + it would be bottom right

Comment: Top of the screen is `0` not `-820`. The top left of the screen is `+0+0`. The top right

Comment: not for me just tried it

Comment: The problem is that you are using `tk.Tk` from multiple threads. Tkinter doesn't allow that. Try keeping all of the tkinter stuff in 1 thread.